# How to use multiple redirect using one javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I tried this code but it unly redirect to one link only

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a class="D-btn" href="https://www.wikihow.com/Block-Page-Redirects" onclick="Atredirect()" target="_blank"><span>Download</span></a> 
  <script> 
    function Atredirect() { setTimeout("location.href='https://gplinks.co/CuM04k'",000);setTimeout("location.href='https://m.facebook.com/',000);}
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would redirecting to more than one link even mean?

Answer (score 0):

Like that may be

```
<a class="D-btn" href="#" onclick="Atredirect()" target="_blank"><span>Download</span></a> 

<script>
  function Atredirect() {
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'https://gplinks.co/CuM04k'; }, 000);
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'https://m.facebook.com/'; }, 000);
  }
</script>
```